# js bar graph for duration in hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-visualization

I need to build a bar graph for duration in hours and minutes, with grouped bar,  for data like

[label, durate_A, durate_B]

[[type_A, 00:30, 07:25], [type_B, 33:14, 7:05], [type_C, 00:00, 09:00]]

I tried to use google charts, i'ts really simple, but seems it doesn't handle duration for scale and Y Axe, so i need to convert the duration in minutes with a good result, but not what i want !

in this example, the blue column has a value of 150 (minutes), but i'll be 02:30

[image]

Can someone tell me what can i use?

P.S. 
I'm developing on RoR :-)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are lots of chart and data visualization  libraries around and all have examples. Asking for recommendations is off topic here

Comment: Ops.... Sorry, i don't know it was OT.

Comment: can some one tell me if google charts definetively doesn't handle time duration? i can change the request if needed

Comment: Thanks, but i can't know all my values

Answer (score 2):

Checkout d3.js (https://d3js.org/).  It's a SVG helper library with a lot of fantastic examples online.

Here's the sample for bar charts. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304